# How can a beta tester who has been added to alpha channel see alpha versions in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

If a Google Play tester is added to the alpha and the beta channels, they will (correctly) see whatever version is newest. So they'll see the alpha build if there is one available and the beta one if not.

However, if they start as a beta tester and are added to a group in the alpha channel, it doesn't seem to work. They still only see beta channel versions no matter if they leave the test, uninstall, etc.

What needs to be reset or changed so that a previous 'beta only' user can correctly be in the alpha and beta channels?

Comment: They are two different testing groups. You need to be added to the Alpha testing group.

Comment: Right. However, if they are in the beta group and testing the app and then later added to the alpha group they will not see alpha versions. This problem persists through reboots, leave the test/return to test, etc.

Comment: If they start in both groups, everything works fine. Its just the adding them later to an alpha group where things don't work correctly.

Comment: Just add them in the beginning or keep everything in beta or alpha.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a solution to the problem

Comment: There is no problem. This is how it works.

Comment: So having a user in beta and alpha at the same time works one way sometimes and a different way the rest of the time? In clear contradiction to what the docs say on the matter? I'm not sure how to make the question more clear, but "This is how it works" doesn't seem accurate.